# make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: makefile

I keep getting this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

Even though my make file looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

all: build

build: inputText.o outputText.o main.o
    gcc main.o inputText.o outputText.o -o main

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c -o main.o

inputText.o: inputText.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) inputText.c -o inputText.o

outputText.o: outputText.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) outputText.c -o outputText.o
```

Yes there should be a tab space underneath the target and there is in my make file.

I can get it to work if I try one of the targets like main.o, inputText.o and outputText.o but can't with either build or all.

EDIT: 
I just randomly tried running make and telling it the file using the following command:

```
make -f make
```

This works but why doesn't just typing make work?

Comment: Can't repro with what you have here. Make sure you don't have funny characters in your file (copy paste what you have here and replace spaces with tabs).

Comment: Your makefile should be named `makefile`, not `make`.

Comment: @PaulR Ahh that fixed it. It wasn't very well explained in my notes that it had to be called makefile.

Comment: You can call it anything you like, but as you found, you then need the `-f` option with `make`. Using the default name of `makefile` just makes life easier. I'll make the above comment an answer for any future travellers along this road.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your makefile should ideally be named `makefile`, not `make`. Note that you can call your makefile anything you like, but as you found, you then need the `-f` option with `make` to specify the name of the makefile. Using the default name of `makefile` just makes life easier.

Comment: Also it should not be named in capital letters.